# Being order of variance leads to order of standard deviation?

Tags: variance, convergence

Is it true to say:
$$a = o\Big(\mathrm{Var}(X)\Big) \implies a = o\Big(\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}\Big)$$
AS I think by the definition of $o$ notation we can have:
\begin{align}
a = o\Big(\mathrm{Var}(X)\Big)  &\implies \frac{a}{\mathrm{Var}(X)} \rightarrow 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \operatorname{Var}(X)>\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}&\\
&\implies \frac{a}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}} \rightarrow0 &\\
&\implies a = o\Big(\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}\Big)&
\end{align}
Am I thinking right? any why?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this exactly corresponds to your question, but here is a result that may be useful in that context

If $E(z_n^2)=O(a_n^2)$, $$z_n=O_p(a_n).$$

Proof: By assumption there is a $M_1$ and $n_\epsilon$, so that 
$$E(z_n^2)<M_1^2a_n^2$$ for $n\geqslant n_\epsilon$. From the Tschebychev inequality  it follows that, for arbitrary $M_2>0$,
$$
\Pr(|z_n|\geqslant M_2a_n)\leqslant\frac{E(z_n^2)}{M_2^2a_n^2}
$$
Now choose, for some $\epsilon>0$, $M_2\geqslant M_1\epsilon^{-1/2}$, so that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Pr(|z_n|/a_n\geqslant M_2)&<&\frac{M_1^2a_n^2}{M_2^2a_n^2}\\
&\leqslant&\frac{M_1^2}{M_1^2\epsilon^{-1}}\\
&=&\epsilon
\end{eqnarray*}

Remark:

If we have $$E(z_n-E(z_n))^2=O(a_n^2)$$ and $$E(z_n)=O(a_n),$$ then 
$$E(z_n^2)=E(z_n-E(z_n))^2+E(z_n)^2$$ implies that $$z_n=O_p(a_n).$$ The rate of the sequence of r.v.s then corresponds to the rate of the standard deviation.